# getting a reference to a MediaElement inside an ItemsControl (WPF)

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

this is a known issue with ItemsControl although I couldn't find a solution :( .

XAML

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="myItemsControl" ItemsSource ="{Binding videos}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="myDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
                <Grid x:Name="sp" Width="300" Height="200">
                    <MediaElement x:Name="myvideo" Loaded="myvideo_Loaded" UnloadedBehavior="Stop"  ScrubbingEnabled="True" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding}" LoadedBehavior= "Play">
                    </MediaElement>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <mt:TouchablePanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>

</Grid>
```

so in behind code I want to do something like

```
private void myvideo_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //myvideo.Play();
    // myvideo.Pause();
}
```

I commented it out to be able to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event handler, you can access the `MediaElement` through the `sender` parameter

```
private void myvideo_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MediaElement myVideo = sender as MediaElement;
    if (myVideo != null)
    {
        myvideo.Play();
    }
}
```

If you want to access the `MediaElement` for a specific item in the `ItemsControl`, you can use the `ItemContainerGenerator` :

```
MediaElement myVideo = null;
FrameworkElement container = myItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(someItem) as FrameworkElement;
if (container != null)
{
    // Note: this works for an ItemsControl, not for a ListBox or ListView...
    ContentPresenter presenter = container as ContentPresenter;
    if (presenter != null)
    {
        myVideo = presenter.ContentTemplate.FindName(myVideo)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll get better answer here, but if not, you can always wrap your MediaElement control into UserControl. In the user control you subscribe to all events you need, and then use the user control inside data template.

:) Hope this helps.